# Nginx user defined rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm wondering why this is question got not asked before: I want let the user make her own rewrite rules but not editing his configuration file.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com: this file (or the original as this file is a symlinkn to sites-available...) is only writeable for root.

As for apache2 we can give him a way to write own rewrite rules, other expires configuration and so on without the need to edit the configuration file in /etc. Let's say it is a hosting provider and the user can't even access the /etc directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `.htaccess` concept is not implemented in nginx, which one of the reasons why nginx is faster,

because if we have a file inside `/var/www/site/folder1/folder2/file.php` for example, the server needs to look for `.htaccess` inside `folder2` and `folder1` and `site`, and each will override the one above it, an overhead for each request.

The only way you might implement a kind of similar thing is add an `include` inside the config file that reads from a certain location

```
server {
   # bla bla
   include /var/www/site1/config.conf;
   location bla {
       # bla bla
   }
}
```

The config file would include server level directives,

Or you could just skip the server block and include files, and those files should include server blocks, but this isn't good because you give them access to the whole server, not just theirs. eg:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site-name
include /var/www/site1/site.conf
include /var/www/site2/site.conf
# etc
```

Basically, my advice, if you really need this functionality, install apache, and maybe just use nginx to server assets and proxy to apache.

Comment: thanks. for now i'm including a file .locations from document root where the user can define own location blocks, rewrite rules and so on. the main difference is that the server has to reload the configuration and a user is not able to reload the configuration.

Comment: if you really want to do that you can try doing a small workaround/hack, create a cronjob that runs every 1 min or 5 min that checks for a certain file, for example `/var/www/site1/.reload` if the file exists delete it and run `sudo service nginx reload`, needs a small bash script to do so